# Create Center-Justified Menu in Fluid Layout

Tags: css, text-alignment, justify

I'm trying to create a "center-justified" menu that maintains its appearance in a fluid layout.

I start with this:

```
ul#top-nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%; }

ul#top-nav li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  margin: 14px 2% 0 0;
  color: #959484;
  text-transform: uppercase; }

ul#top-nav li:last-of-type {
  margin: 14px 0 0 0; }
```

And that yields me this, which is exactly what I want:

[image: Proper Alignment]

But, when the width of the browser window expands, the margins don't scale properly, and I get this:

[image: Improper Alignment]

I know that I can put in media queries that adjust the `<li>` element's margin percentage, but I'd rather have it be truly fluid. I also know that there are probably jQuery approaches to this, but I'd like to keep it in CSS, if possible.

Ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I used Paulie_D's suggestion (thank you!), and it worked, but now I'm struggling with the spacing being inconsistent between the elements:

[image: Inconsistent Spacing]

What do I do about that?

Comment: could you provide a quick jsfiddle? That way we can garrentee if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use `text-align: justify;` on your list and center it with `margin: 0 auto;`

2) Add a pseudo element to stretch the items to max width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/cvcusrLL/4/)** (I added a border to visualize the efect)

```css
.wpr {
  border-top: 2px solid #111;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #111;
}
ul {
  text-align: justify;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">VISIT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">EXHIBITIONS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">COLLECTIONS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">LEARN</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that CSS table layout is what you are looking for.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqt6ok06/1/)

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #ccc;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 6</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 7</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 8</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```